# New array need to generated using existing array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I would like to compare my existing array (timestamp, value) with previous minute value

Say for example

```
Array1 = [[key1, v1] [key2, v2] [key3, v3] [key4, v4]]
```

and would like to generate a new array like

```
Array2 = [[key2, v2-v1] [key3, v3-v2] [key4, v4-v3]]
```

here key is timestamp

Comment: Have you made any attempts? If so, you should share that as well.

Comment: Using a `dict` to keep those key values would be more efficient. `collections.OrderedDict` to preserve order.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to solve it:

```
Array1 = [['key1', 1], ['key2', 2], ['key3', 3], ['key4', 4]]

array2 = []
for i, elem in enumerate(Array1[1:]):
    array2.append([elem[0], elem[1] - Array1[i][1]])

print(array2)
```

You iterate over the elements of `Array1` starting from the second element and you keep the `key` as it is, while you compute the second element as the difference of the current element minus the previous element value (i.e. `Array1[i][1]`, since `i` starts from `0`).
This prints:

```
[['key2', 1], ['key3', 1], ['key4', 1]]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` and slice your original index to start at the first index such as

```
res = [[v[0], f'{arr_1[i+1][1]}-{arr_1[i][1]}'] for i, v in enumerate(arr_1[1:])]
# [['key2', 'v2-v1'], ['key3', 'v3-v2'], ['key4', 'v4-v3']]
```

Expanded Loop:

```
res = []
for i, v in enumerate(arr_1[1:]):
    res.append([v[0], f'{arr_1[i+1][1]}-{arr_1[i][1]}'])
```